# WooCommerce - Redirect to another page after removing last item from the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I only need this to happen in `CART Page` and not while removing items from Cart Menu or Mini-Cart.

After removing the last item from the CART Page (assuming the cart is now empty), I need to redirect the user to another page. Unfortunately, my method is not working.

```
function action_woocommerce_cart_item_removed( $cart_item_key, $instance ) { 
    global $woocommerce;
    if(is_cart() && $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){ //currently in the cart page and the cart is now empty.
        wp_redirect('some-page'); //leave the cart page and redirect to another page.
        exit();
    } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'action_woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Is cart item removal happening using AJAX request? If so then this will not work. Or if it is not possile you have to it by JS code  
`jQuery(document.body).on('removed_from_cart updated_cart_totals', function () {
    location.reload();
});`

Comment: Yes, the removal happened using AJAX request.

Comment: Your problem is that is_cart() will not be returned as true in your function ever.

Comment: I also tried using `is_page('cart')` still not working.

Comment: @ZianTapChan you find this question answer?